# HTML emails, Outlook 2007 specific - How to fix 'Spacing between text in same <strong> tag'

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

Testing email template in litmus and can't work out why Outlook 2007 adds a big space for text nested within a `<strong>`, `<a>`, `<td>`, `<tr>` tag. Please note, the button works in all other clients.

Tried adding various inline-CSS like line-height, mso-line-height: exactly;

```
<!--CTA-->
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#009cb3" width="200" height="60" style="-webkit-border-radius: 100px; -moz-border-radius: 100px; border-radius: 100px;">
                        <a class="bg-rollover" href="" target="_blank" style="font-size:14px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;padding:28px 12px;display:inline-block;width:200px;border:1px solid #009cb3;-webkit-border-radius: 100px; -moz-border-radius: 100px; border-radius: 100px;">
                        <strong style="text-transform:uppercase;">button text</strong>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<!--End of CTA-->
```

I expected the output to have a small gap between the two lines of text.

Comment: "I expected the output to have a small gap between the two lines of text." - Which two lines of text? The only text I see is "button text".

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use VML to get the button to work in Outlook. For those interested, the code is below but please note you have to change the href and button text in both the VML and HTML.

```
<!--CTA-->
   <tr>
      <td align="center">
         <div>
         <!--[if mso]>
            <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#" style="height:60px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#ffbb00" fillcolor="#ffbb00">
               <w:anchorlock/>
               <center style="color:#041857;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">CTA text</center>
            </v:roundrect>
         <![endif]-->
            <a href="#" style="background-color:#ffbb00;border:1px solid #ffbb00;-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;color:#041857;display:inline-block;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:24px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;font-weight:bold; padding: 12px 18px;">CTA text</a>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
<!--End of CTA-->
```

Although VML was replaced by SVG, old versions of Outlook use Microsoft Word to render emails. Word recognises VML so it's useful to use if things aren't rendering as expected in Outlook.